# Unable to use Variables from __init__ method in another method of the same class

Tags: python, oop

```py
class Window:
    def __int__(self, width, height, fps):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.fps = fps
        self.screen_size = (self.width, self.height)

    def set_window(self):
        global screen, screen_rect
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.screen_size)
        screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        return screen, screen_rect
```

But I am Getting this error:
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'screen_size'

Comment: `__int__` is not `__init__`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

correct `__int__` to `__init__` and it should work...

Comment: Typo questions can and should just be closed, not just answered.